# font-size not working in IE edge for placeholder

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I am working on a web application, just found few issue in ie edge. One of them is font-size property is ignored in IE Edge for placeholder. It's quite strange.
Also found it's known issue and already reported.
Does anyone knows  any workaround ?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search"/>

input::-ms-input-placeholder{color:#f00; font-size:50px;}
```

example:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqvLdG

Comment: Is changing the font-size of the input itself an option?

Comment: yes. Changing font-size of input will change the placeholder font-size. But I want to change only placeholder font size.

Comment: Depending on how important this is, you could try changing the font-size with JavaScript in the focus and blur events.

Answer (score 3):

There is bug: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/3901363/
In Creators update it will be fixed.
Right now : apply all style by default, add class when some data is entered. Then you have separated state of placeholder and it will work on IE Edge

Comment: That bug is not about font-size.  It is about placeholders not being visible in certain circumstances.

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed as of May 2018.  Microsoft resolved this bug as "By Design": https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/11342294/  Another (unanswered) bug report for the same issue: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4355171/

Comment: Yeah @NealGokli, you have in some terms right. But they limit all solutions with "work as design" so no straightforward solution. I can add that font size isn't work but will have same as opacity response from MS team.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. You can use transform to adjust the font size.

```
input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: red;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-0.1rem);
}
```